# CefSharp WinForms - Flickering when page loading

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp.WinForms version  84.4.10.

My application is a wip game launcher for the games I make.
[Screenshot of the launcher.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aifdK.png)
There is a Main form that loads and unloads child forms when buttons are pressed. The child forms contain a panel stretched to fill the whole child form. The CefSharp is initialized on the panel.
Here's the code that does that:

```
    public CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    private void Changelog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://aerial-knightstudios.com/store/akslauncher/")
        {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        Size = new Size(600, 600),
        Location = new Point(200, 200),                
        };
        this.panelChangelogPage.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
```

When the child form is enabled, a black box appears that fills half the form then it flickers white then the webpage loads.

#### So far I have tried the following:

I have turned on double buffering by adding `DoubleBuffered = true;` inside `public FormMain()` and this made the flickering less intense, but it still flickers a lot.

I also changed `[STAThread]` in program.cs to `[MTAThread]`. This also helped, but very slightly.

Any solutions are welcome.

Comment: Is it rapidly switching focus between the forms? It's unlikely it's actually flickering

Comment: @amaitland No it's not. I think it appears to flicker because of how brief the black box appears.

Comment: Have you tested with different hardware?  Please fork https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and provide an example that reproduces the problem,  push your changes to GitHub,  keep them minimum, just enough to reproduce the problem.  Squash them into a single commit. No zip files of code, I won't open them.